# How to send email as a independent code for faster response?

Tags: java

On click of a submit button , i am calling a Jersey REST Web-service which is responsible to

```
1 .Insert record in the database 
2.And send email .
```

This is my code

```
if (operation.equals("Insert")) {
        String SQLInsertMgmtUser = "INSERT INTO User (depotID , emp_ID , appUserName)VALUES(? , ? , ?)";
        String sendEmail =  SendEmailUtility.sendmail(empmail, generatedPwd_str);
    } 

public static String sendmail(String sendemalto,String generatedpwd) throws IOException 
{
        String result = "fail";
        Properties props_load = getProperties();
        try {
            // Code to send the email Using java mail API 
            result = "success";
        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            result = "fail";
            logger.error("Exception Occured"+ "sendemalto" +sendemalto , e);
        }
        return result;
    }


public static Properties getProperties()   
{
          if (props == null) {
           File configDir = new File(System.getProperty("catalina.base"), "conf");
           File configFile = new File(configDir, "email.properties");
           InputStream stream = null;
        try {
            stream = new FileInputStream(configFile);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            logger.error("exception" , e);
        }
           props = new Properties();
           try {
            props.load(stream);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            logger.error("exception" , e);
        }
       }
       return props; 
  }
```

This code works fine , but the issue i am facing with this code is that the Submit  Operation is nearly **taking 15 seconds** .

My question is that , is it possible to run the send email code as a  independent thread .

Please share your views as how to approach this requirement .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplest way to execute a task asynchronously is by using an `ExecutorService`.

Something like this:

```
public YourClass {

    private    ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);

   public void yourMethod() {
     if (operation.equals("Insert")) {
       String SQLInsertMgmtUser = "INSERT INTO User (depotID , emp_ID , appUserName)VALUES(? , ? , ?)";
       executorService.execute(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            SendEmailUtility.sendmail(empmail, generatedPwd_str);
         }
      });
   } 
}
```

Comment: Thank you , i am using it in a REST Webservice , what should be the appropiate value to be defined ?? and is it safe to use that inside webservice

Answer (score 0):

I would setup a localhost MTA (like OpenSMTPD) which then relays to your real MTA ("Satellite Mode"). This gives you a local queue. If it takes a few seconds to send the message to your remote MTA, that's okay as the local MTA will handle that.

This also has the advantage of centralized configuration if you want to share the MTA among multiple applications.